# Nested for-loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Ok so I am brand new to R and am having trouble implementing a nested for-loop for a simulation.  The goal of this code is supposed to be that for two beta distributions, every result that has a probability greater than 1/2, a counter is incremented.   Then based off this counter a probability is calculated by dividing by N (the population size).  However, I would like this to run for a range of n values and create a distribution of those probabilities(p) that result for each n value. I am having difficulties implementing this though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Code for inner for-loop:

```
    n = 5000
    counter = 0
    x = rbeta(n,3,1)
    y = rbeta(n,3,1)

    for (i in 1:n)
    {
      if((y[i]-x[i] >= 1/2))
      {
       counter = counter +1
      }
    }
    p = counter / n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate `p`, you can just do `p <- mean( y - x > 1/2)`. To do this for a range of values of `n`, create a vector of values `n.range` and do

```
n.range <- seq(100, 5000, 100)
p <- rep(NA, length(n.range))
for(n in n.range){
    x <-  rbeta(n,3,1)
    y <-  rbeta(n,3,1)
    p[n == n.range] <- mean(y - x > 1/2)
}
hist(p)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do! Thank you for the help!